# Liferay Portlet Responsive design

Tags: primefaces, frameworks, responsive-design, liferay

Hi guy I need to build a portal using liferay. in the requirements, The portal should be responsive.  We don't want to use jsp . Now we are using jsf 2.x using primeface to build portlets but i fear doing lot of customisation on UI (crucial part) with this framework in the futur.
I need advices (pro & cons) for frameworks to in liferay project with less developpement time, great web responsiveness. should i consider developing portlet using jsp mvcPortlet and use AlloyUI to customise UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new alloy: components shown at the [Liferay Faces Showcase](http://www.liferayfaces.org/web/guest/showcase) work directly with Liferay Portal's bootstrap integration for responsive JSF. For more information see the [Liferay Faces 4.2.0-m2 release announcement](http://www.liferay.com/web/neil.griffin/blog/-/blogs/announcement-liferay-faces-4-2-0-m2-released).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know very well primeface couse usually a i develop with mvc pattern.

However i can tell you that mvc is the standard for Liferay and from version 6.2 bootstrap 2.3.2 CSS are natively included (not the JS part!). Also Liferay layout template follows the bootstrap classes and no more aui classes.

So i think that if you using Liferay 6.2 JSP/MVC/Bootstrap is certainly the faster and easier way.

Sorry if I could not compare better the two patterns!

Answer (score 0):

The liferay (especially the 6.2) has some responsive built in functionality.

You can add responsive future to your page using only css.
The portlets in liferay by default fills out all the container. So actually it fills out your layout.

That means if you add responsive future to your layout you automatically applied that to your portlet too. (If the box is switched than the content of your box is switched too. like: http://kolozsvaros.ro/web/kolozsvaros/fooldal )

For usage check this page:
https://www.liferay.com/web/nathan.cavanaugh/blog/-/blogs/liferay-com-mobile-sites-and-responsive-layouts